# Difference between using Car and parce que, and why?

Tags: vocabulaire

Some tutorials use "car" to mean "because" in English and others use "parce que".

Please explain the difference and why each is used.

Answer (score 5):

The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/car) replies to this question:

> Rem. 2. *Car/Parce que*, *Car/Puisque*. Contrairement à *car*, *parce que* et *puisque* peuvent être utilisés après certaines conj. de coordination : *et*, *mais*, *ni parce que* ou *et*, *mais*, *ni puisque*; de même ils peuvent être repris par que : *parce que... et que* ou *puisque... et que*. D'autre part, *parce que* peut introduire une prop. en réponse à la question *pourquoi ?*, s'employer derrière des adv. tels que *précisément*, *justement*, *uniquement*, *seulement*, *surtout*..., après le tour uniceptif *ne... que* et le présentatif *c'est*, tous emplois impossibles avec *car*. La conj. *car* qui introduit une explication peut avoir la même valeur que *puisque*, qui garantit le bien-fondé véridique de l'énoncé

In summary:

- Both are often interchangeable.
- *Car* cannot be used after *et*, *mais*, *ni*, some adverbs and *c'est*.
- *[Parce que](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parce%20que)* is used to reply to a question starting with *pourquoi*, *car* can't be used in that case.

Moreover, *car* (as a coordinating conjunction) is rarer and slightly formal.

Comment: I was also taught that *car* was more formal. In Canada, however, it's much more informal and can easily be heard in everyday speech, a development owed perhaps to its being so short.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I just discovered this question is a duplicate. Curiously, someone wrote *car* is rare in Quebec French.

Comment: That's interesting. I should have clarified that by far the biggest part of my experience of Canadian French is Ontarian French; maybe this is a more isolated phenomenon than I thought.